# How to set not null for function params in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating one function in `Kotlin`. It validates email and password fields. I want to apply email and password should not be null. `@NotNull` kinda annotation here.

Does anyone know how to do this in `Kotlin`? So the caller cannot send the null value.

```
private fun isEmailAndPasswordValid(email: String, password: String): Boolean {

    if (email.isEmpty()) return false

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) return false

    if (password.isEmpty()) return false

    return true
}
```

Comment: You’re using not nullable type `String` already?

Comment: String is not nullable type ? I see that java has @NotNull annotation for these

Comment: In Kotlin `String` is not nullable, you need to add a question mark to make it nullable: `String?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin differentiates all types by **nullable** and **not-nullable**. For example, the class `String` can be used for the type `String`, which is not nullable, and the type `String?`, which IS nullable, i.e. could hold `null`.

In your example no nullable types are used, so you’re all good - no additional annotation needed.

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) should be studied for further information.

Comment: Thank you what If I have custom type in params in this method and need to make not null then what is the way to do this in Kotlin ?

Comment: Even custom types work like this. If you have a class `Person` the type `Person` cannot be null. Only `Person?` could

Comment: So suppose if I have fun `do(person: Person?) { }` and How should I call it ? What to check before calling this function. like this `do(?person)`

Comment: In the function you have to handle the nullability of `person`, you will see when you try it

Comment: Look at the link I shared in the answer

Comment: I read so I have to do like this `if(person != null) { do(person) }`

Comment: This is possible:)

Comment: Can we do `do(person?)`  safe calls ?

Comment: This can be achieved with `let`: person?.let{}

Answer (score 3):

The Kotlin language is by default null-safe so when creating a new variable it can't be null, but when you want a nullable variable you can add The exclamation mark to specify that it can be null for Example String?, Int? ...

Not Nullable

```
var a: String = "bachiri"
a = null // compilation error
```

Nullable Type

```
var a: String? = "bachiri"
a = null // OK
```

and bare in mind if you want to call a function on the nullable Type you should use eighter the check for null variable(1) or use the safe calls(2)

Comment: So suppose if I have `fun do(person: Person?) { }` and Should I call it `do(?person)` ?

Comment: nn if you have a function with a nullable type you can call it normally but the function should be aware that the params are null

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin has build-in null safety. `String` is a non-null type while `String?` is a nullable type. So, `isEmailAndPasswordValid(email: String, password: String)` will enforce the value passed to it is non-null.

Answer (score 1):

When I check the Kotlin documentation, I can see that a String variable can't be set to null, unless you declare it can be, and your compiler will raise an error.

> For example, a regular variable of type String can not hold null

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: Thank you what If I have custom type in params in this method and need to make not null then what is the way to do this in Kotlin ?

Comment: Then I would suggest you to do a safe call, like `obj?.method()` then the method is only executed when `obj` is not null. You can also use the `!!` parameter, which will raise an NPE exception if the object is null.

Comment: Thank you Giovanni :) +1

Comment: @Williams a variable of "custom type" still cannot be null if the type is not nullable. If a type does not end with `?` it _cannot_ be set to null.